# Angularjs: Create an array of keys from json object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, angularjs

I have a json in the following structure:

```
$scope.hi=[{
"a":1,
"b":true,
"c":"great"
}];
```

I want to extract only the keys and make an array like

```
$scope.bye=["a","b","c"];
```

Though seems to be a very basic question but would be very helpful for me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is what you need

```
Object.keys($scope.hi[0]);
```

This only works in IE9+ if you target IE.

An alternative might be to do fetch them with a loop

```
var obj = $scope.hi[0],
    array = [];

for (key in obj) {
   if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
       array.push(key);
   }
}
```

Also note that the order of the keys may not be respected depending on the browser implementation.

Comment: Keep in mind that `Object.keys` does not exist in IE <= 8 https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys

Comment: @aduch: knew about this but needed a generalized solution which works in older browsers also if available.

Answer (score 2):

You can use #aduch variant or start to use great lib that called [underscorejs](http://underscorejs.org/#keys)

```
_.keys($scope.hi) // result: ["a","b","c"]
```

Comment: It doesn't seems appropriate to use a library for a single assignment.

Comment: it make sense to use this lib in your project as it really flexible.

Answer (score 1):

Just as @aduch said, use

```
Object.keys($scope.hi[0]).
```

Add the following code before making use of it to handle browsers that do not implement Object.keys

```
// From https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys
if (!Object.keys) {
  Object.keys = (function () {
    'use strict';
    var hasOwnProperty = Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty,
        hasDontEnumBug = !({toString: null}).propertyIsEnumerable('toString'),
        dontEnums = [
          'toString',
          'toLocaleString',
          'valueOf',
          'hasOwnProperty',
          'isPrototypeOf',
          'propertyIsEnumerable',
          'constructor'
        ],
        dontEnumsLength = dontEnums.length;

    return function (obj) {
      if (typeof obj !== 'object' && (typeof obj !== 'function' || obj === null)) {
        throw new TypeError('Object.keys called on non-object');
      }

      var result = [], prop, i;

      for (prop in obj) {
        if (hasOwnProperty.call(obj, prop)) {
          result.push(prop);
        }
      }

      if (hasDontEnumBug) {
        for (i = 0; i < dontEnumsLength; i++) {
          if (hasOwnProperty.call(obj, dontEnums[i])) {
            result.push(dontEnums[i]);
          }
        }
      }
      return result;
    };
  }());
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys